# Array Formula Problem - How to Fill In Blank Rows with the Same Value before a Breakpoint which advances to the next letter

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I have a Google Sheet which is grouped into segments of a TV show.  So there's an **A** segment and then a **B** segment and so on ...  I have allocated two columns to provide two different timing functions (COLUMN "K" and COLUMN "L").

I figured out how to create an array formula to incrementally label the first row of each segment (see COLUMN "M").  **But - what I **REALLY** need and CANNOT figure out is how to repeat the segment letters in each of the rows belonging to the segment, prior to it incrementing to the next letter.**  I get into trouble trying to process formulas that pertain to the same column the ARRAY FORMULA lives in.  That's the trap I'm in right now.   That's why you see the blanks in COLUMN "M".

I have also figured out (by researching and looking at other examples) how to use an array formula with a  breakpoint to restart renumbering sequences (see COLUMN "P").  Although, in this last case, I first had to create a column with a repeating number in it so I could increment it .(you'll see that COLUMN "P" makes use of COLUMN "O" for this purpose although logically I would have preferred not to do that - seems kinda dumb)

BTW - COLUMN "N" is designed for "first and last" -- the "0" and "99" are used elsewhere to establish range length for summing values in each of the segments.  So I'd like to keep those, if possible.  **Or, better yet, have a more convenient way of placing 99 as the last row in COLUMN "P" before resetting to 0 again and then incrementing up from there .**

The columns on the extreme left - COLUMN "A" and COLUMN "B" do this stuff the "old fashioned way" - with formulas in each row - so you can see what my intentions were - but I don't like those - because the formula is required in each row and adding or deleting rows creates havoc -- and besides, I'm now addicted to ARRAYFORMULA methods because it's so nifty and clean to have one column-topping formula that does all the work!  That's why I'm trying to replace everything over on the right side - as you can see...

In case you're wondering, the light green boxes with red borders represent cells with array formulas in them.  A way for me to signal to myself where the action lives.

**Here's a copy of the spreadsheet with edit rights** - feel free to copy the sheet **GARY TEST PAGE** to a new page and edit as you wish:

[DEMO SHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vine1TeG24XIKwfaCZvm7JUjjLTN9tSH-e2J_k6DkYM/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks for helping!

Hit me up with any questions or needed clarifications at your leisure.

Gary

Comment: I know your post seems very clear to you, but that is because you can see your sheet and you know your end goal. It will be easier for the volunteer contributors here to help you if you share a link to the spreadsheet (or a copy of it), with the link's permission set (when you create the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Comment: Hi. Two things: 1) Please add an example of a successful outcome to both your spreadsheet AND your question (snapshot).  2) "I figured out how to create an array formula to incrementally label the first row of each segment (see COLUMN "M")" There's no `arrayformula` in Column M? Is this a typo?